# Proof that $\partial A= \overline{A}-\text{Int}(A)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $\partial A= \overline{A}-\text{Int}(A)$, so for the first inlcusion:

Let $x \in \partial A$, then for all $\varepsilon > 0$ we have that

$$B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$$

From the second afirmation i can say that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \nsubseteq  (A^c)^c=A$, this means that $x \notin \text{Int}(A)$, and by the first claim we have that $x \in \overline{A}$

Well, maybe this can work so for the another inclusion take $x \in \overline{A}-\text{Int}(A)$, then for all $\delta > 0$ is clear that:

$$B_{\delta}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad B_{\delta}(x) \nsubseteq A$$

perhaps

$$B_{\delta}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad B_{\delta}(x) \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$$

From where $x \in \partial A$

Can this solution work?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. Usually, the boundary is just defined to be $\text{Bd} A = \text{Cl} A - \text{Int} A$. It naturally follows that for any $x \in \text{Bd} A$, that each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X - A$.